# Making <img> clickable inside a <div> tag

Tags: html, css, image, href

I currently have some trouble with IE11 and below.

I have a  around a  tag which looks like this:

```
<div class="cursor_pointer" data-href="/de/S/palettieren_umreifen/paletten/Paletten.html">
    <img title="Paletten" alt="Paletten" src="/medias/sys_master/had/h00/8854080749598/8802146943006_SB50-D_1696_psd.png" />
</div>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
sethrefs = function () {

if (document.querySelectorAll) {

    var datahrefs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-href]'),
            dhcount = datahrefs.length;

    while (dhcount-- > 0) {

        var ele = datahrefs[dhcount],
                link = function (event) {

                    var target = event.target,
                            leftclicked = ('buttons' in event && event.buttons === 1) ? true : 
                                                        ('which' in event && event.which === 1) ? true : 
                                                        (event.button === 1) ? true : false;

                    if (!event.target.href) window.location.href = this.getAttribute('data-href');

                };

        if(ele.addEventListener) ele.addEventListener('click', link, false);
        else ele.attachEvent('onclick', link);

    }

  }
};

sethrefs();
```

what I want to have is that if you click on the image you can access the site. On every other browser it's working fine but not in IE 11 and below. Is it because he cant handle the data-href call?

I just tried to give it some z-index but without any effect.

Comment: where is code??

Comment: Don't worry about the fast downvotes, just try to post the code :)

Comment: :) looks exactly like what? joking, but would be nice to have the code also.

Comment: Never heard of auto interpret `data-href` as a clickable element. I think you have javascript code for your `.cursor_pointer` element which will do the magic.

Comment: Why not using `a` instead of `div` and convert it to a block with CSS?

Comment: Our customer want it that way. The reason for that way is, it's better for search-engine optimisation (That's their reason for our request to just put an <a> tag around it :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data-href` attribute is a **custom data-* attribute**. It's great if it works as you wish on other browsers (*which I didn't know myself*), but the data attributes are made to apply some data and trigger **JS events** in your HTML elements.
See [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) for compatibility
You could use a classic `<a href="your/link.html"></a>` or use the JS **[dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)** :

```
var dataLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.cursor_pointer');
dataLinks.forEach(function (link) {
    link.onclick = function() {
        window.location.href = link.dataset.href;
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**
*(Following the conversation in the comments of my answer)*
Put the data-href to any element you want. Select elements with `data-href` attribute and apply the function to them. You will need to polyfill [`NodeList.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) (`document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` for which `forEach` isn't supported by IE/Edge actually).

```
<!-- both div and img have the data-href attribute -->
<div class="cursor_pointer" data-href="/de/S/palettieren_umreifen/paletten/Paletten.html">
    <img data-href="/de/S/palettieren_umreifen/paletten/Paletten.html" title="Paletten" alt="Paletten" src="/medias/sys_master/had/h00/8854080749598/8802146943006_SB50-D_1696_psd.png" />
</div>
```

And then the JS:

```
// NodeList.forEach isn't supported by MS browsers
if (!NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "forEach", {
        value: Array.prototype.forEach,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    });
}

var dataLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[data-href]');
dataLinks.forEach(function (link) {
    link.onclick = function() {
        window.location.href = link.dataset.href;
    }
});
```

Comment: I have it exactly running like that. But I can only get on the other page if I click slightly beside the image. Somehow the img is above the div without any z-index property on it. I just tested it with giving my div some z-index so it is definelty above the img but thats not working either

Comment: I see.. that's because the link function isn't inherited for the image element. You'd be better using a `<a>` I guess

Comment: Is it possible to make it inherited with javascript?

Comment: You could apply this function by adding the class  `cursor_pointer` manually to the child elements, or by selecting them in the `forEach` like `var childElements = link.querySelectorAll('*');` and then apply the same function on click with another nested `forEach`. I'm not sure if it would work for 3 nested elements. If it doesn't, you would need to make a recursive function. I'd try but I'm actually on phone.

Comment: Sadly it's not working either with adding the    cursor_pointer class to the img. The point is there is no magic happening on the class cursor_pointer. It's just there for some specific styling.

Comment: I edited my answer. Adding the class was an error (my fault) as the children elements don't have `data-href` attribute.

Comment: sorry for replying so late. The funny thing is if i'm putting an alert into the function the alert gets shown as soon as I click on the image but it's not working with the data-href thingy.

Comment: hello @DanielHalling I edited my answer once again because the `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` isn't supported by MS browsers (which I didn't know when I wrote). I don't get the alert thing, what happens when you click now with the updated answer ?

Comment: Hey AymDev I just edited my initial entry with the current JS i'm using. It works fine in firefox and chrome

Comment: @DanielHalling in Firefox & Chrome only ??

Comment: it's working great with your code :) Cheers @AymDev :)

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to wrap the `img` inside an `a` element.

```
<div>
    <a href="link.html"><img src="yolo.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: that was my first thought as well but there is a script running in there which generates the data-href. The point is it's running on every other browser except IE 11 and below. In Microsoft Edge it's working as well. If I click a little bit beside the image the link is working fine though